# Get translated results from Google webpages by python or other programming languages

Tags: java, c#, php, python, google-translate

How to develop a small software, as long as the specified url (eg.www.foxnews.com) and the target language (eg.Chinese), then the software will automatically call google translation results.

url:www.foxnews.com

Reulst:

```
<html>
Translated web content
</html>
```

Google webpage translation api:

`https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=zh-CN&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=www.foxnews.com&edit-text=&act=url`

Program development language is not limited, python, php, c#, java, etc.

I wrote a small program test in Python,but it doesn't work well!

reuslt：

```
other code...
<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-scripts allow-popups" src="https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_p?hl=en&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=auto&sp=nmt4&tl=zh-CN&u=http://www.foxnews.com/&depth=4&xid=25657,15700021,15700124,15700149,15700186,15700191,15700201,15700214&usg=ALkJrhgAAAAAW6Tq8NE5bkJZI9Rp_GhWRVSdEja6ZjXB" name=c frameborder="0" style="height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;bottom:0px;"></iframe>
other code...
```

The translated result contains the iframe, but I want the translation result in the iframe.

```
#coding:utf-8
import os
import codecs       
import requests

  def write_file(filename, content, encoding='gbk', mode='a+'):
  dir_name = os.path.dirname(filename).strip()
  if os.path.exists(dir_name) is False:
    os.makedirs(dir_name)
    with codecs.open(filename=filename, mode=mode, encoding=encoding) as f:
    return f.write(content + '\r\n')

  if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = 'https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_p?hl=en&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=auto&sp=nmt4&tl=zh-CN&u=http://www.foxnews.com/&depth=3xid=25657,15700021,15700124,15700149,15700186,15700191,15700201,15700214&usg=ALkJrhgAAAAAW6SrzEpQsnIHKUKB7HmJz2Hr1IlZZbNC'
    r = requests.get(url=url)
    html = r.text
    write_file(filename='./a.html', content=html, mode='w', encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to use google cloud for this.
[Cloud Translation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/)

edit:
after creating a google cloud account use this API for translation

```
POST https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2
```

[documentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/translate)

Comment: Please add some details as to how Cloud Translation could help solve this problem.